Using String manipulation functions in Mule <logger element
I need to print a portion of the String variable value to the Mule console using Mule <logger>. I am not sure if it is possible to use substring function within the logger. However, when I tried the following syntax, I get the error that reference to the substring function not found.
Syntax::
<logger message="#[substring(vars.topicDetails, 10, 50)]" level="INFO"/>
<logger message="#[vars.topicDetails.substring(10, 50)]" level="INFO"/>

Error: Unable to resolve reference of: 'substring' . at 1 : 1"
I am using Mule 4.6 version. Note that I am not looking for DW script using variables. Instead, the requirement is to print on Mule console using Mule <logger> component which print output to console.
Thanks.

It seems that there is a confusion about how to use expressions in Mule 4. I'm guessing that the variable is a String, which may be internally a Java String. That doesn't mean that you can execute Java instance methods directly in a Mule 4 expression. Mule 4.x expression language is actually DataWeave 2.x. So every time you write an expression using the syntax #[...] you are writing a DataWeave expression. Even if it is a logger or some other component.
Going to how to extract a substring of a String in DataWeave, the core list of functions there is no substring() function. You have to use one of these alternatives:

The range selector allows to select a range of an Array or String. Example: #[vars.topicDetails[2 to 5]]. For input "123456789" the output is "2345".
Use the substring() function in the Strings module, added in Mule 4.4.0. If you are using an older version of Mule this function will not be available. To avoid using import in a short expression we can use the full module name to reference the function. Example: #[dw::core::Strings::substring(vars.topicDetails, 1, 5)]. For input "123456789" the output is "2345". Using import just makes the expression a bit longer: #[import * from dw::core::Strings --- substring(vars.topicDetails, 1, 5)]


Thank you for the response. I tried both way and still get the exact same error . Unable to resolve reference  of : 'dw::core::String .......' at 1 : 1"

Did you try with the selector? Add the complete error and any additional lines to the question. Also the value of the variable.

Also add to the question the component that you are testing as XML. Use [edit] to update the question.

Please use below in logger
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
var text = "hello world!"
substring(text, 1, 5)
dw functions can be used in logger and it will print
